# when onscrollchangelistener scroll with webview then app crashing on given scrollY

Tags: java, android

Sorry for weak english

hello i am new in android studio i dont know how can i set onscrollchangelistener on webView. When i am using onscrollchangelistener with webView then on the given scrollY value app crashing

below my code

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, final int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
           if (scrollY>200) {
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).hide();
           }
           else  if (scrollY==0)
           {
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).show();
           }
           else
           {
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).show();
           }
            }
        });
    }
```

thanks hopes help stackOverFlow

Comment: please add crash log here

Comment: no any error in log actually app not crash webview are start shaking for some second when scrollY>200

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isAnimated = false;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        webView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, final int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
           if (scrollY>200 && !isAnimated ) {
               isAnimated = true;
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).hide();
           }
           else  if (scrollY==0)
           {
               isAnimated = false;
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).show();
           }
           else
           {
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);
               Objects.requireNonNull(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()).show();
           }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i am used it its not working one more thing i am using Fragment for tabLayout